# Measuring the Angle of a Triangle with a Protractor (Question Illustrated by Image)

Tags: triangles, angle

Forgive my ignorance, and teach me the correct way to read an angle when I am using a protractor. From the image below, would any of the two statements below be correct? If yes, which one? If neither, what would be the correct way to state the angle of the triangle of the chart?

Statements:

1. Relative to March 18th, the triangle formed by the number of cases is roughly at a 30 degrees angle
2. Relative to March 18th, the triangle formed by the number of cases is roughly at a 150 degrees angle

Protractor superimposed on a bars-chart visualization of the number of COVID-19 cases:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Angle is formed by two rays. When measuring an angle, you have starting ray (zero) and terminal ray. If starting ray corresponds to black zero, use black numbers, if it correspond to the blue zero, use blue numbers. In this case, use blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the angle is taken as the smallest one, but I don't know if there is any agreement for the type of data you are using.

Edit: Thinking in angles of a triangle, that angle have to be less than $90°$, if not there is no triangle, because you already have an angle of $90°$.

Answer (score 0):

If you're measuring the interior angle of the blue "triangle," it's $30$ degrees.

The supplement of the angle is $150$ degrees. It's the angle as measured from the "negative X axis" which points into the past.

To figure out which is which from the protractor, put your finger at one of the zeroes and sweep your finger up to the measured angle. You're sweeping through the appropriate angle as you do this.